# Indian customs rules on bringing packed iPhone

Tags: customs-and-immigration, cellphones, us-citizens, local-customs

I am a US citizen, who is a Person's of Indian Origin (PIO) card holder. I am planning to buy an iPhone 6s (60 rupees) as a gift for my mother (who lives in India). I would like to bring it to her in an unopened box.

Will I have a problem at Indian Customs for bringing in an unopened, brand new iPhone, along with my old iPhone which I am using?

Comment: What is a PIO card? What is the significance of the 60 rupees?

Comment: As long as you declare it, you would have absolutely no problems.

Answer (score 1):

> Tourists of foreign origin, other than those of Pakistani origin
>   coming from Pakistan, coming to India by Air.  (i) used personal
>   effects (ii) articles (other than those mentioned in Annex-I above)
>   upto a value of Rs. 8000 for personal use of the tourist or as gifts
>   and  travel souvenirs if these are carried on the person or in the
>   accompanied baggage of the passenger.

http://www.cbec.gov.in/htdocs-cbec/customs/cs-act/formatted-htmls/bgge-rules1998-ason11July2014

http://www.customsmumbaiairport.gov.in/forms/Content.aspx?LinkID=64